# ember-pre4 action helper does not pass browser event anymore?

Tags: ember.js

Hi i have the following code in my template:

```
<div {{action "play" this target="view"}}>{{title}}</div>
```

and the following code in my view:

```
MB3.PlaylistView = Ember.View.extend({
  play: function(event) {
  }
});
```

the parameter event passed to the play function is now the playlist model (passed as "this" in the action helper shown above)

In Ember-pre2 the parameter passed to the action handler recieved the browser event with attributes like `currentTarget` etc. and a property context where the model was in.

How can i access the native event's parameters like `currentTarget` in ember-pre4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of discussion on this ticket as well:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1684

The recommended solution would be to create a custom view and then define a click handler. The click handler will be passed the event as the first argument.

```
MB3.PlayButtonView = Em.View.extend({
  click: function(event){
  ... click handler
  }
});
```

Comment: Using an `action` I can pass in the model as a parameter, but dont have access to the event. With the `click` function I get the event, but how do I access the corresponding model?

Comment: In your view you can do something like this.get('controller.content'). This will vary depending on what content you have and what is bound to the view.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I have a list of items and need to know if the ctrl key was pressed while clicking on one. Using `this.get('')` I sure can access my models, but I then have to bring the `event target` and the `model` together manually. May work but doesn't quite feel right. Is there another way or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 1):

this is by intention but there is an improvment issue for that, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1986